# getting error message when using an iterator on STL map

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to print out map elements but I am getting a error message everytime I assign the iterator to the map. The error message is so long and not readable..please help :p

```
//a.h
#include<string>
#include<map>
class B; //forward declaration of class B
class A
{
     typedef std::map<std::string, B *> container;
     private:
     std::string name;
     container Bs;

     public:
     void printAllBs() const;

     typedef container::iterator set_itr_T;
};

//a.cpp
#include<a.h>
#include<string>
#include<map>
#include<b.h>
#include<iostream>

void A::printAllBs() const
{
   for(set_itr_T it = Bs.begin(); it!=Bs.end(); ++it) //error here
   {}
}
```

Comment: We still need the error message, please paste it in your question. It might not be readable to you but it should be to others.

Comment: Your iterator needs to be a constant iterator: for(container::const_iterator it = Bs.begin(); it!=Bs.end(); ++it) //error here

Comment: See the answer Yang gave below.  You have two choices, use a const_iterator because you declare the method as 'const' or redeclare the method without const and use the existing implementation as-is.

Answer (score 3):

Since you declare the function

```
void A::printAllBs() const
{
   for(set_itr_T it = Bs.begin(); it!=Bs.end(); ++it) //error here
   {}
}
```

as `const`, the compiler needs to make sure it does not change anything in `container`. Thus, `it` must to be a `const_iterator` of `container`. You have to use

```
for(container::const_iterator it = Bs.begin(); it!=Bs.end(); ++it)
```

or remove `const` from the method declaration.

Comment: By the way, I did this while using Set, why the compiler allowing set to using set_itr_T?

Comment: The `set` elements are automatically `const`. You cannot change an element in a `set`.